# Failing to draw Image to JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, image, swing, jframe

first I want to apologize for any mistakes, I'm not speaking english well, I'm new to Java and I'm new to Stackoverflow. Please be kind!

I keep failing to draw a simple image to screen. I tried everything, but I keep failing and I'm getting more and more confused. Here's my Sourcecode:

```
package com.Animation;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")

public class Class1 extends JFrame{

private BufferedImage backgroundImg;

public Class1(){
    this.setTitle("Animation");
    this.setSize(1080, 720);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    LoadContent();
    }


public static void main(String[] args){
    new Class1();
}

private void LoadContent()
{
    try
    {
        URL backgroundImgUrl = this.getClass().getResource("Back.jpg");
        backgroundImg = ImageIO.read(backgroundImgUrl);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Fehler!");
    }
}

public void Draw(Graphics2D g2d)
{
    g2d.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, null);
}

}
```

So what happens is, that a JFrame window opens with nothing to see on it. I think that's beacuse the Draw() method doesn't get called. But when I add like "Draw(g2d);" somewhere, I keep getting a NullPointerException. The picture "Back.jpg" is located in the same package as the class. I'm using eClipse and the JRE JavaSE 1.7.

I really hope you can help me, im totally exhausted by all my tries to figure out what's the problem. It would be cool if you could write the correct code into the answers and explain what I've done wrong. Remember, I'm new to all this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of ways to do that. Examples

1) `JLabel`.  //Not recommended
Add the `JLabel` in your `JFrame`, then do `label.setIcon(backgroundImg);`

2) `JPanel`
Override the `paint()` method in `JPanel`(make sure you've added it to your `JFrame`).

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, this); 
}
```

Comment: How do I add it to my JFrame?

Comment: After `LoadContent();`, add `add(label);` or `add(panel)` then put `pack();`.

Comment: Learn Java first. You have to construct a new `JPanel`, initialize it, the add these codes `add(panel); pack();` after `LoadContent();` and before `}`

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Here I have set the image to a JPanel instead of directly setting it to JFrame.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/**
 *
 * @author Rumesh
 */
public class Test extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = buildFrame();

        final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("1.jpg"));

        JPanel pane = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };


        frame.add(pane);
    }


    private static JFrame buildFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        return frame;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add a description of why your code solves the problem, so that the question asker can learn what they were doing wrong.

Comment: As Arkanon already said, I'm not able to see why you've done it like that. So I copied the code and replaced some object names with mine, but I'm getting a huge amount of errors.

Comment: Can you tell me what are the errors? As in why it did not work with your code, I am not sure why. So that's why I created an alternative way for you to achieve your task. If you can provide the errors you got with my code, I will help you to solve them.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
 at com.Animation.Class1.main(Class1.java:17)

Comment: @Joey, properly caused the file can't be founded, You should not copy + paste his code directly, instead, you should modify it. (You should replace `1.jpg` with `Back.jpg`

Comment: Like @Jeremy has mentioned it is because the program cannot find the file. Error itself says "Unknown Source".

Comment: 1) `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);` should be `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);` 2) A `File` won't work at time of deployment.  Use an `URL` instead.

Comment: g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); will work in this context. Agree on your point about using URL.

Comment: @Jeremy of course I modified the code. The system still returns this error message. That's exactly my problem.

Comment: *"`g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);` will work in this context"*  We should build robust classes that ***do not depend on 'context'***.  Minus one for promulgating fragile code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're searching for:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("src/media/Image.jpg");
JLabel lblImg = new JLabel("", image, JLabel.CENTER);
lblImg.setBounds(..., ..., ..., ...);
add(lblImg);
```

This way you'll add an image to a JLabel and than place it on the screen. I hope it helps in some way.

Comment: 1) A `File` won't work at time of deployment.  Use an `URL` instead. 2) Use `ImageIO` for feedback when loading the image.  The `ImageIcon` constructor will fail silently.

Comment: Worked for me, though.

Comment: Then apparently you don't deploy your projects, or don't deploy them as Jars.

Comment: Now I understand, indeed I don't.